# How to read/interrogate a filesystem and file structure

Tags: c++

As a first time programming using vi with a raw Linux terminal in C++, what is the simplest way to recurse through a filesystem and get results such as file size, date, directory date etc?

I imagine I'm missing a library or two that would handle this pretty cleanly which would be great to know. Even better would be knowing where to find a solid reference for the basics like this.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/filesystem

Answer (score 5):

If you have a modern compiler you can use std::filesystem:

https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem

Otherwise you can use boost::filesystem, which is very similar but non standard:

https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_67_0/libs/filesystem/doc/index.htm

Boost is a collection of libraries with various purposes and a focus on quality. Boost libraries regularly end up in the new C++ standards so it's good thing to learn.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I'm after. Incidentally I did actually find this page in my research but missed the tiny text suggesting it was an importable library, so I didn't really know what I was reading about.

Comment: In large projects I am familiar with boost, however also familiar with the circa 10 GB disk space required on the development machine and the hours long compile it requires..! I was pretty sure there was a simple standard way of doing it that has been around forever.

Comment: std::filesystem is standard (C++17), and boost::filesystem is a not a header only library so probably not the worse regarding compile time (and it doesn't force you to use all of boost)

Comment: I'm compelled to ask now how modern a compiler I need to get hold of the filesystem include. I'm working with g++ 4.8.5.

Comment: @J Collins I'm not entirely sure, but I think gcc 7.3 or later should get you going.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support

Answer (score 2):

You might consider (on Linux at least) to use [nftw(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/nftw.3.html). You could use [opendir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/opendir.3.html) + [readdir(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html) + `closedir` with [stat(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/stat.2.html) (and `nftw` is using all these). See also [syscalls(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/syscalls.2.html) (and read some Linux programming book, perhaps the old [ALP](http://www.cse.hcmut.edu.vn/~hungnq/courses/nap/alp.pdf)). Notice that on Linux (and POSIX systems), the operating system API is in C, not in C++.

Of course, you might use the C++ functions given in [f4's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51087412/841108) (they are are based on functions above).

And you could use C++ frameworks such as [boost](http://boost.org/), [poco](http://pocoproject.org/), [Qt](http://qt.io/) (also using the functions above).